# how to remove source audio file in html5 audio player via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, avaudioplayer

I have a dynamic audio player (default html5) where I can set the src and it auto plays. That is all working. I also have a link to remove the src, **but none of the following lines actually** removes and/or resets the player to delete/remove the source audio file. If you play the audio, then stop it and click the delete audio file, the player STILL will play the existing audio file. So 
how to remove the source audio file from the player in javascript?

```
                  jQuery('#audioPlayer"').replaceWith('<img id="audioPlayer" src="">');
                  jQuery('#MP3').replaceWith('<img id="MP3" src="">');

                  var mediaPlayer1 = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
                  var mediaPlayer2 = document.getElementById("MP3");

                  mediaPlayer1.src ='';
                  mediaPlayer1.removeAttribute("src");
                  mediaPlayer1.load();
                  mediaPlayer2.src ='';
                  mediaPlayer2.removeAttribute("src");
                  mediaPlayer1.attr('src', '')
                  mediaPlayer1.children('source').prop('src', '');
                  mediaPlayer2.children('source').prop('src', '');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove the `src` **attribute**, you're just removing `src` from the HTML representation of the `audio` element.

The underlying JavaScript `HTMLAudioElement` still has a `src` **property** when you do that, so just remove the `src` **property**.

A minimal solution in native JavaScript would be something like `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].src = '';`

Of course, you should not replace the `audio` tag with an `img` tag before doing that

```js
document.getElementById('removeSourceProperty').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].src = '';
});

document.getElementById('removeSourceAttribute').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].removeAttribute('src');
});
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" src="https://cdn.bitdegree.org/learn/I_Cactus_-_05_-_ruby_cactus.mp3?raw=true"></audio>
  
<div>
    <button id="removeSourceAttribute">Remove source attribute (HTML only)</button>
    <button id="removeSourceProperty">Remove source property (Works!)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `audio.src = ''` displays a warning in the console: `Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed`. Is there a way to do that without the warning? Also, `audio.removeAttribute('src')` does not remove the audio from the track, and it can be played again pressing the "play" button.

Comment: @Rodrigo this may be an implementation-dependent thing because I get no warning in Chrome. I guess you should not worry about it. In which browser did you get this warning by the way, Firefox?

Comment: Yes, Firefox. I guess I'll have to live with, but I hate unnecessary warnings on the console :(

Comment: This warning looks strange to me because empty string is the default value for `src` (when not provided) so I don't get why Firefox wants to parse it

Comment: `A = document.createElement('audio'); console.log(A.src); A.src = ''; console.log(A.src);` This will output two different values: `<empty string>` and `http://localhost/`. Strange!

Comment: Setting `audio.src = ""` actually sets the `src` to the current page's URL (hence the warning). A network request is actually made to the page and even though it most likely won't get any meaningful audio, it's not good. This is similar to setting an `img.src = ""`, it displays a broken image because most likely your current URL is a HTML.